# Find words with numbers sql like

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There is a `table1`

```
| ID  | Attr       |
+-----+------------+ 
| 169 | Jur9       |
| 169 | Jur9_name  |
| 169 | Jur10      |
| 169 | Jur10_name |
```

And query:

```
select *
  from table1
 where ID = 169
   and ATTR like 'Jur_';
```

Result:

```
| ID  | Attr       |
+-----+------------+ 
| 169 | Jur9       |
```

I expect the result:

```
| ID  | Attr       |
+-----+------------+ 
| 169 | Jur9       |
| 169 | Jur10      |
```

Comment: What is the pattern that you need to match? Is it anything beginning with 'Jur' and ending in a number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_` wildcard matches exactly one character.  So this expression:

```
WHERE ATTR like 'Jur_'
```

Is looking for `ATTR` values that are four characters that start with `'Jur'`.

You can do what you want using `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE`:

```
WHERE ATTR LIKE 'Jur%' AND ATTR NOT LIKE 'JUR%$_%' ESCAPE '$'
```

That is, followed by anything but not followed by an underscore.

Or, you can use `regexp_like()`:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ATTR, '^JUR[^_]+$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select *
  from table1
 where ID = 169
   and ATTR not like '%_name'
```